# hide/Show to div's simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6wEzF/)

```
    <div class="sidebarmenu" style="position: absolute; left: -200000px">
         Show/hide div
    </div>
    <div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: -200000px">
        <img src="http://diymusician.cdbaby.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Builder-of-the-House.jpg">
    </div>
```

On click, the ".sidebarmenu" is toggled. I want the ".image" to toggle along with the div. How can I do that?

Comment: This is a very bad way to make toggling! Use `toggle` or `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` or simple `show`/`hide`

Comment: You should include all your source here, even if you have it in a Fiddle / jsBin / PasteBin, etc. Our corporate proxy blocks jsFiddle for example, so I can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target multiple elements, separate each with a comma `,`

e.g: `$('.sidebarmenu, .image')`

```
 $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
        $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
        if(hidden){
            $('.sidebarmenu, .image').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: -200000
            })
        } else {
            $('.sidebarmenu, .image').css({
                position: '',
                left: 0
            })
        }
        $('.sidebarmenu, .image').data("hidden", !hidden);

    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wEzF/1/)

Simplify your code with jquery [**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$('.sidebarmenu, .image').toggle();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `, .image` to the selector. Your selector should look like this

```
$('.sidebarmenu, .image').css({
```

Answer (score 2):

You've overcomplicated this. This is what you want:

```
 $('#showmenu').click(function() {
     $('.sidebarmenu, .image').toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

and image to your selector

```
 $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
    $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
    if(hidden){
        $('.sidebarmenu,.image').css({
                     //-^^^^^^---here
            position: 'absolute',
            left: -200000
        })
    } else {
        $('.sidebarmenu,.image').css({
                      //-^^^^^^---here
            position: '',
            left: 0
        })
    }
    $('.sidebarmenu').data("hidden", !hidden);

});
```

recommened you to have a look at `toggle()` function too
[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6wEzF/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
        $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
        if(hidden){
            $('.sidebarmenu, .image').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: -200000
            })
        } else {
            $('.sidebarmenu, .image').css({
                position: '',
                left: 0
            })
        }
        $('.sidebarmenu, .image').data("hidden", !hidden);

    });
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6wEzF/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wEzF/6/)

```
 $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('.sidebarmenu').toggle();
    $('.image').toggle();
 });
```